# how to design ejs page with materialize css

Tags: node.js, materialize, ejs

I am working with nodejs for communicating with server and storing and retrieving data to and from database. It works fine for me.

I'm building a web application for that i used view engine ejs.
Now,what i want is to design my ejs page using materialize css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following in your `layout.ejs` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just link the materialize css file into the page that you want to use it in.